# Having trouble with an element switch

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to do an element switch. Basically switch two elements in a 2D array. I am not getting any errors but it just doesn't work out right, and doesn't even print all of the elements. What am I doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
public class ArrayTheory
{
    public static void printArray(int[][]args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<args.length; i++)
            for(int j=0;j<args.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(args[i][j]);
            }   
            System.out.println();
    }

    public static void arraySwitch(int c1, int c2, int [][]args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<args.length; i++)
            for(int j=0;j<args.length; j++) {
                int temp = args[i][c1];
                args[i][c1] = args[i][c2];
                args[i][c1] = temp;
            }   
    }
}
```

And here are the elements

```
public class TestArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] test = {{1,2,3,4},
                        {1,2,3,4},
                        {1,2,3,4}};


        int[][] carData = {{16,2008,4},
                           {45,2011,4},
                           {26,2010,7},
                           {18,2009,8}};

        ArrayTheory.arraySwitch(0,2,test);
        ArrayTheory.printArray(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with the output you get and what you expect

Answer (score 1):

Since the array isn't square you you need to index the second dimension with `args[0].length` or `args[i].length` if each row doesn't have the same length.

Comment: Yes, that's not only a problem when switching elements, but also when printing the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your code in the inner loop of `arraySwitch`

```
        int temp = args[i][c1];
        args[i][c1] = args[i][c2];
        args[i][c1] = temp;  <<<<<<< bug
```

That should be

```
        args[i][c2] = temp;
```

Comment: And additionally you have a bug described in the answer of @FDinoff

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.  If you are trying to swap two specific elements, then you need four coordinates (a1, a2) and (b1, b2) to address each element.  Your code seems to be trying to swap two rows.  Your print method looks fine, except your outer loop does not have braces.  So your println() will only execute once, after the entire contents of the 2D array have been printed.